# Visual Studio 2015 - Report Viewer 2015 redistributable - Getting Report Viewer "12" working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, reportviewer

I'm running **SQL 2014**, and some users are having problems with the Report Viewer 11 control (Redistributable 2012), so I want to give the "**Report Viewer 12**" new control (**Report Viewer Redistributable 2015**) a spin.  But this doesn't seem to be working from the steps I've tried so far, and as of the time I'm writing this there seems limited information on the newer control, and just information of workarounds for the old one.

Anyone get this new one working?  Steps to Reproduce?

I'm looking into the solution, and it appears adding the feature via the installer (SQL Data tools) should help.  But I'm surprised there is not Nuget Package or etc.  And such little documentation covering the new version.  Too Bleeding edge?

**Update:** I installed SQL Data Tools via 2015 installer (modified installation and choose new feature).  But now I'm jumping a couple more hurdles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I did get this working...

1. I modified the VS 2015 installation to add SQL Data Tools
2. I uninstalled the Nuget Package for 11, because we want 12
3. I added a reference to Microsoft.Reporting.Web (12) which was an option thanks to step 1
4. I updated any left over references in my Web.config from version 11 to version 12
5. I created a new fresh form.aspx
6. I added a script manager
7. Via the design view I dragged a 12 report viewer control onto my page
8. I configured the report viewer as I regularly would

   asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">/asp:ScriptManager>

Comment: v12 still requires IE (not Edge/Chrome/etc) if you want Zoom control or print control.  Seems disappointing that this control is stuck so far backwards in time.  Kinda hurts SQL Server 2014 and etc, as it weakens their SSRS product.